# Unwanted space appearing under nested table in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a problem with white space appearing in at the bottom of a nested table. It only occurs if the contents of the main table cell row has data which vertically makes the cell height higher than the data contents in the nested table. E.g. a description field caused this to occur when the nested table cell only had a link to one item. I hope that make sense. Please see attached screenshot. (The screenshot is a very crude view of some demo data as I could not use the actual information, but I have modified it to show the same result).

Is there a way that I can make the nested table cell vertically full the whole cell so that the report looks clean and doesn't have white space appearing at the bottom?

[image]

Comment: i have changed methode of asking thanks

Comment: i have 4 day in this problem a can t avance

Comment: Don't post everywhere the same issue. As I have told you there is no solution to controlling the  height combined with tablix nesting.

Comment: ok  thanks for you

Comment: i fonund in tablix propreties named line height he accept expression i thinks  the solution exist in him

Answer (score 1):

Use a single tablix.
To emulate cell merging:

Create a total for the value you need for the merged cell under the related group and make it hidden (red color)

For the "merged" cell expression use

```
= Iif(RunningValue( Fields!rg2.Value,CountDistinct,"rg1")=1, ReportItems!Textbox12.Value, Nothing)
```

The expression checks the distinct count of group2 values. If its 1 (first cell) returns the value of the total otherwise nothing.

To make the cell look as one use the following border expressions

top border:

```
=Iif(RunningValue( Fields!rg2.Value,CountDistinct,"rg1")=1, "Solid", "None")
```

botton border:

```
= Iif(RunningValue( Fields!rg2.Value,CountDistinct,"rg1") = CountDistinct(Fields!rg2.Value, "rg1"), "Solid", "None")
```

[image]

[image]